# Lagrange theorem question

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to teach myself group theory and this question is the final one in an exercise on Lagrange theorem and it has me currently stumped.

Finite group ${G}$ contains distinct elements ${a}$ and ${b}$ and identity ${e}$, such that: ${a*b=a^3*b^4}$ and ${a^4*b^3=e}$. Show that ${a^2=e}$ and that the order of ${G}$ is a multiple of 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof that $a^2=e$:

$a^4*b^3=e$. Multiply both sides by $b$ from right to get to $a^4*b^4=b$. This combined with the assumption that $a*b=a^3*b^4$, implies $a*a*b=b$ (more details: $a^4*b^4=a*a^3*b^4=a*a*b$). Multiply both sides by $b^{-1}$ to get to $a*a=e$ or $a^2=e$.

Proof that $|G|$ is a multiple of $6$:

First we prove that $b^3=e$.
We know that $a*b=a^3*b^4$ and $a^2=e$, hence $a*b=a^2*a*b^4=a*b^4$. So by multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ from left and then by $b^{-1}$, we get to $b^3=e$.

By now, we know that $G$ has an element of order $2$ and an element of order $3$. It means that $|G|$ must be a multiple of $2$ and $3$. Hence $|G|$ is a multiple of $6$ nad we're done!

Answer (score 0):

1st question : $a^4*b^3=e \Rightarrow b^3 = a^{-4}$ and
$$a*b = a*a^2*b^3*b \Rightarrow e=a^2*b^3 = a^2 * a^{-4} = a^{-2}$$
so $a^2 = (a^{-2})^{-1} = e$.